# Console.log() shows undefined before getting data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I seem to have a lifecycle hook issue that I can't seem to solve.

```
export default class EditRevision extends Component {

  state = {
    data: [],
    customColumns: []
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/lagbevakning/revision/subscriptions?id=' + (this.props.match.params.id)).then(response => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.data,
          loading: false
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    /* THIS IS THE CONSOLE.LOG() I AM REFERRING TO */
    console.log(this.state.data.subscriptionRevisionDTOS) 
    return (  
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is my *log* upon rendering the component 
https://i.gyazo.com/9dcf4d13b96cdd2c3527e36224df0004.png
[image: Console.log()]

It is undefined, then retrieves the data as i desire it to, then it gets undefined again.

Any suggestions on what causes this issue is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: because this.state.data.subscriptionRevisionDTOS is not defined in state ,on load data is empty so its showing undefined,
please upload whole component code

Comment: You should also put the api call code in componentDidMount instead of willMount

Comment: The API response seems to be an object? But in your initial state, `data` is an empty array.

Comment: you should use componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount, 'case this is deprecated

Comment: um I think your this is out of reference, meaning i think using this inside the axios object refects to that object instead of an object of your required class. could you try consoling like console.log(this) inside the then function

Comment: What is the content of `response.data`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/lagbevakning/revision/subscriptions?id=' + (this.props.match.params.id)).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            data: response.data,
            loading: false
        })
    })
```

with:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        customColumns: []
    }

    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/lagbevakning/revision/subscriptions?id=' + (this.props.match.params.id)).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            data: response.data,
            loading: false
        })
    })
}
```

try to call axios in constructor or componentDidMount() (componentWillMount should not be used). the undefined result is caused by the async call. Looks like you have a lot of uncontrolled renders. try to add a shouldComponentUpdate function or convert your component in a PureComponent

Take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class EditRevision extends Component {

  state = {
   data:{subscriptionRevisionDTOS:[]},
   customColumns: []
 }

 componentDidMount = () => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/lagbevakning/revision/subscriptions?id=' + 
  (this.props.match.params.id)).then(response => {
    this.setState({
      data: response.data,
      loading: false
    })
  })

  render() {
    /* THIS IS THE CONSOLE.LOG() I AM REFERRING TO */
    console.log(this.state.data.subscriptionRevisionDTOS) 
    return (  
      <div></div>
    )
  }
```

see this it should be like this

Comment: Hi Kishan,
i've tried this already and this gives me syntax error.

console.log(this.state.data.subscriptionRevisionDTOS[0])
this is how it should be, but this also gives me syntax error because it gets back undefined.

Comment: console.log(this.state.data),console only this you will not get undefined , you will get empty array and once api gives you response your array will get updated

Answer (score 0):

You have init the state with

```
state = {
    data: [],
    customColumns: []
 }
```

Here `this.state.data` is empty array which did not have definition of 
**subscriptionRevisionDTOS** that is why you are getting `this.state.data.subscriptionRevisionDTOS` `undefined`.

Meanwhile, your `async`axios.get call is completed and `this.state.data` is updated with `subscriptionRevisionDTOS`.

As soon as `state` is updated render() called again and you are getting the proper value of `this.state.data.subscriptionRevisionDTOS`.

So below line will surely work.

```
state = {
   data:{subscriptionRevisionDTOS:[]},
   customColumns: []
 }
```